# Check if the formula is identically true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have a [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc1J5.png):

$$
(A \supset C) \supset \Big((B \supset C) \supset \big((A \vee B) \supset C\big)\Big)
$$

How can i verify that it is identically true? I wanted to build a truth table, but I don't understand how interpret the symbol that the set implies another set.

Comment: It doesn't mean "superset" here: it means "implies".

Comment: If more familiar, your statement is equivalent to $$(A \Rightarrow C) \implies \Big((B \Rightarrow C) \Rightarrow \big((A \vee B) \Rightarrow C\big)\Big)$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael where can we find more info about that symbol? Is the symbol equal to $\implies$ or $\;\Longleftarrow\;$?

Comment: @Brian To be honest, I don't understand why it is equivalent

Comment: @Brian Shouldn't the implication be in the opposite direction?

Comment: @bvl It is only a matter of notation. $A \supset B$ and $A \implies B$ both denote the material implication "If $A$, then $B$". You may find the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) on material conditions helpful, and the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) that lists common mathematical symbols/

Comment: @Brian Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the symbol $\def\to{\supset}\to$ is *ye olde* symbol for the conditional connective (aka material implication).  Well, it is useful to know when reading historical works, and *some* modern textbooks do still use it for unknown reasons (...it is almost 2020, people!).

Anyway, a proof by cases states that $C$ is derived from assumptions of $A\lor B$ and $B\to C$ and $A\to C$.  So applying deduction theorem to discharge the assumptions gives a natural deduction proof for the statement $(A\to C)\to((B\to C)\to((A\vee B)\to C))$

- No premises

  - Assume $A\to C$

    - Assume $B\to C$

      - Assume $A\vee B$

        - Assuming $A$, derive $C$ by modus ponens.
        - Assuming $B$, derive $C$ by modus ponens.
      - Thus $C$ via a proof by cases (aka disjunction elimination).
    - Thus $(A\vee B)\to C$ via a conditional proof (aka conditional introduction).
  - Thus $(B\to C)\to((A\vee B)\to C)$ via likewise.
- Therefore $(A\to C)\to((B\to C)\to((A\vee B)\to C))$ via likewise.

So to build your truth table:$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c}A&B&C&A\to C&B\to C&A\lor B&(A\lor B)\to C&(B\to C)\to ((A\lor B)\to C)&(A\to C)\to((B\to C)\to((A\lor B)\to C))\\\hline \top&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top \\ \vdots&\ddots\end{array}}$$